# Lookup table with function pointers, is it possible to map various indices to one function?

Tags: c, function-pointers, lookup

I'm trying to implement a simple lexer and therefore have to implement a finite state machine. I chose the function pointer approach instead of the nested switch statement.

The problem is, in some states, nearly all possibilities map to the same function.
In one state (the START state) I need to determine what kind of token i just read. Especially single-char tokens. I need to recognize a whitespace, a colon, a semicolon, brackets, etc.
But in the other states, all the single-char tokens just end the current token and therefore always call the same function no matter which single-char token occured.
Here is an example:

```
Token next(Tokenizer *tokenizer) {
        static void (*const mapper[STATES][OUTGOING_EDGES])(State *, Token *, Tokenizer *) = 
      { /*the function pointers, if im in the START STATE*/
           alpha,
           digit,
           whitespace,
           colon,
           semicolon,
           //many more single char tokens.
      },
      {/*another state that is NOT the START STATE.*/
            alpha,
            digit,
            end_token, //whitespace just ends the token
            end_token, //so does a colon
            end_token, //and a semicolon
            //many more function calls to the end_token function
      },
      { ..... }, ...
};
```

is it somehow possible to write the `end_token` just once, but have this function from the current index to the end?

So for example, lets say my array has the following dimensions and i have 4 calls to my function named end_token. Is it possible to write it somehow like this:

```
static void (*const mapper[1][5](State *, Token *, Tokenizer *) = {
    {alpha, end_token},
};
```

and when I call `mapper[1][4](...)` i actually call the function named end_token?
I suspect, that this is not possible, but maybe you know some tricks. Thank you!

Comment: are you using `gcc`? `[1..4] = undefined`

Comment: Another option is to leave them as NULL and then in the invoking code have logic that maps NULL to undefined. That may or may not be appropriate depending on your full requirements.

Comment: You can use designated initializers to set the non-default values, and then leave the rest initialized to NULL — `static FunctionPtrType mapper[STATES][EDGES] = { { [0] = alpha, [1] = digit }, { [2] = something, [7] = anotherthing }, ... };` Your code running through the table then needs to treat a NULL pointer as equivalent to `undefined`.  And that sort of thing is a good reason to introduce a typedef for the function type: `typedef void (*FunctionPtrType)(State *, Token *, Tokenizer *);` — a type which I assumed in the array definition.

Comment: excuse me, my description was a little bit unclear. "undefined" is actually a pretty bad name. A better name would be "end" or something like that. Imagine reading a word, lets say "int" and then a whitespace. Now I know "int" is finished. But it could also be a ";" instead of a whitespace. This also ends the "int" keyword. So any kind of terminator will end the reading process.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the updated information, I think my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257380/lookup-table-with-function-pointers-is-it-possible-to-map-various-indices-to-on#comment125956164_71257380) provides a decent outline of what to do.  The one downside of C initializers is that there's only one default value, which is zero or null.

C99 provides [designated initializers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9).  GCC provides a [useful extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits), but you have to be careful to separate the `...` from the leading number in the range.

<sup>*Note carefully the difference between triple-dot `...` and the 'more information here' ellipsis `…` in the code below; it isn't an accident!*</sup>

You could apply them to your scenario like this:

```
typedef void (*FunctionPtrType)(State *, Token *, Tokenizer *);

// Names for state numbers
enum { S_START, S_CONT1, … };
// Names for tokens. T_ZZZZZ is a dummy; it gives the count of other numbers
enum { T_ALPHA, T_DIGIT, T_WHISP, T_COLON, T_SEMIC, … T_ZZZZZ };

static const FunctionPtrType mapper[STATES][EDGES] =
{
    [S_START] =
    {
        [T_ALPHA] = alpha,
        [T_DIGIT] = digit,
        [T_SEMIC] = semicolon,
        [T_COLON] = colon,
        [T_WHISP] = whitespace,
        …
    },
    [S_CONT1] =
    {
        [T_ALPHA] = alpha,
        [T_DIGIT] = digit,
        …
    },
    …
};
```

Those elements not explicitly initialized would be given a null pointer.
Your code running through the table then needs to treat a NULL pointer as equivalent to `end_token`.

With the GCC extension, you could arrange for a non-null default to cover the general case and then override that for the entries that you want to provide a non-default value:

```
    { [0 ... (T_ZZZZZ - 1)] = general_case,
      [T_ABCDE] = abcde,
      [T_PQRST] = pqrst,
      …
    },
```

The compiler might warn about the overrides — that would be a nuisance.